I'm trying to replicate the script used on Kaggle for DAX ESG Media Dataset . it download the CSV file and nothing will work
the file name is SDG alignment with DAX companies - Swisstext 2023.ipynb.
I'm using colaboratory (https://colab.research.google.com/drive) to work on the script and I just get errors
I download the files on colaboratory which works and them try installing but it won't work. I'm at my wits end. I still need to try and work in the data.
This is the first bit of code on kaggle which I think is the start of my problem

In this cell, set DATA_DIR to the directory from which both files can be read.

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive/', force_remount=True)

DATA_DIR = "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/dax_esg_dataset/"`

I tried changing the this to mirror a file I worked on in the past by didn't work

Download Lending Club data from Excel

DATA_DIR = pd.read_csv("esg_documents_for_dax_companies.csv")

changing file names as needed
This is the second part of the error
when I try to is install this , I also get error message

Make sure that all dependencies are installed.

import sentence_transformers

I tried using import pip install sentence_transformers
All I got was more error
